# martingale under probability

Tags: probability

A process ${Y_n}, n=1,..,N$is called predictable if $Y_n$ only depends on $(w_1,w_2,..,w_{n-1})$ for all $n$. Particularly, $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ should be constants. Suppose $\{X_n\}, n=0,..,N$ is a  a martingale under probability $\{p,q\}$ and $\{Y_n\}, n=0,..,N$ is predictable process. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-X_{k-1}) Y_k$$ is  martingale under probability $\{p,q\}$.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Using the linearity and the stability properties of the conditional expectation we get :
$$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  E( (\sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k +(X_{n+1}-X_{n})Y_{n+1} )/ F_n)$$
$$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k + E(   (X_{n+1}-X_{n})Y_{n+1} /F_n )= \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k + Y_{n+1} E(   (X_{n+1}-X_{n})/F_n )$$
Then $$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k $$

Answer (score 0):

Using the linearity and the stability properties of the conditional expectation we get :
$$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  E( (\sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k +(X_{n+1}-X_{n})Y_{n+1} )/ F_n)$$
$$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k + E(   (X_{n+1}-X_{n})Y_{n+1} /F_n )= \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k + Y_{n+1} E(   (X_{n+1}-X_{n})/F_n )$$
Then $$E( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k/ F_n)=  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_k-X_{k-1})Y_k $$